# Select min date after selected date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a schema that looks like this:

```
------------------------------------
ID | Time | Type | Description | obj
------------------------------------
```

And some data will be like

```
1 | 01/01/1900 01:01:01 AM | 1 | Start | O1
2 | 01/01/1900 01:01:02 AM | 1 | Start | O2
3 | 01/01/1900 01:01:03 AM | 2 | Stop  | O1
4 | 01/01/1900 01:01:04 AM | 2 | Stop  | O2
```

Notes:

- The O1, O2 etc. is the ID of the object that the process operated on. It will be consistent between the start/stop times, but there will be multiple start/stop times for each object (the process will start and finish operating on a specific object multiple times, and my query will need to select records for each time the process processed that object)
- The description says Start/Stop for the benefit of this question's clarity. In practice, it has all kinds of data that is parsed out.

So, what I need are the pairs of start times and stop times that are closest to each other. Stated another way: for every start time, I need the next closest stop time. So the result of a select statement for the sample data above (that only selected ids) would return:

> (1, 3)
>
> (2, 4)

What I've tried:

```
SELECT  obj, 
        [Time] AS StartTime, 
        (SELECT MIN([TIME]) AS t
         FROM   TheTable
         WHERE  [Type] = 2
         HAVING MIN([Time]) > StartTime) AS StopTime
FROM     TheTable
WHERE    [Type] = 1;
```

This obviously doesn't work as StartTime is unknown to the inner select.
Without the Having clause in the inner select, it runs but I get the same StopTime for all entries, as you would expect. Which is, of course, not what I need.

Is there any way that I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.obj, t1.Time as Start, min(t2.Time) as Stop
FROM TheTable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TheTable t2
ON t1.obj = t2.obj and t2.Description = 'Stop' and t2.Time > t1.time
WHERE t1.Description = 'Start' 
GROUP BY (t1.obj, t1.Time, t1.Description, t2.Description)
```

left outer join because there might be a start time and not yet a stop time

Comment: You, sir or madam, deserve much thanks. The only modification I needed was >= because I noticed instances where it started and stopped near instantly, and added OR statements for other types of STOP descriptions. >edit: accept answer button is erring out. Will accept it asap.

Comment: Thanks. btw, I used "Description", but you can replace it all with "type" instead, as you did in your query. As for the StartTime, in your query, it isn't recognized because it is an alias for a selected column. But you can also do it with your query by removing the "Having" and placing it in the "Where" of your subquery: `Select obj, [Time] As StartTime, (SELECT MIN([TIME]) AS t FROM TheTable a WHERE a.[Type] = 2 and a.obj = b.obj and a.[Time] >= b.[Time]) AS StopTime FROM TheTable b Where [type] = 1`

Comment: Hi user16484, it's great approach. But still I am doubtful why column references in having clause didnt work..see my answer for details..and share if you have any info?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it doesn't work.

You can always use outer column reference in SubQ, you are missing a 'comma' and 'group by' BTW

```
SELECT  obj, 
       [Time] AS StartTime,
       (SELECT MIN([TIME]) AS t
         FROM   TheTable
         WHERE  [Type] = 2
         and t1.obj = obj
         HAVING t > StartTime) AS StopTime
FROM     TheTable t1
WHERE    [Type] = 1
group by obj,TIME;
```

EDIT:

I am not expert in SQL server and have no idea why the column alias is not working. This query works in other Dbs like Teradata which I was using. Anyhow, you can use table alias to workaround this.

```
SELECT  obj, 
   [TIME] AS StartTime,
   (SELECT MIN([TIME]) As [tt]
     FROM   TheTable
     WHERE  [Type] = 2
    and t1.obj = obj
     HAVING MIN([TIME]) > t1.TIME
      ) AS StopTime
FROM     TheTable t1
WHERE    [Type] = 1
group by obj,TIME;
```

SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a745/14

Now, it seems that column alias is not allowed in Having clause in SQL server:

```
SELECT  obj, 
   min([tdate]) AS StartTime from thetable group by obj having starttime>5 ;
```

Invalid column name 'starttime'.: SELECT obj, min([tdate]) AS StartTime from thetable group by obj having starttime>5

Comment: Yeah, I was missing a comma in my post here. Not so in my actual query. I'm still getting "Invalid column name 'StartTime'." and I'm not sure why. As it is, I can't even use the `t` alias in the subq HAVING without getting the same message for `t`.

Comment: I just tried. Not quite. I'm getting NULLs for StopTime. The other answer is working however. I thank you for your input, as it still helps me better understand what I was originally trying to write.

Comment: That's OK if you accept other answer. I am more about learning what the actual problem was. See my edited answer and you'll get the reason of your failure "Invalid column name"..BTW replace > with >= in my query too and you may get correct results of second query .. SQLfiddle shows correct results..!!

Comment: @user2407394, providing your `t1.tdate` is `t1.Time`, your final query should work (though you don't need the group by at the end)

Comment: yeah i tried with diffrent column names in sqlfiddle, so missed some names while copying..!!